# SqlConnection is null - Possible Reasons?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was following this tutorial in order to get a dropdown menu working with a database:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/binding-dropdownlist-in-mvc-in-various-ways-in-mvc-with-data/

However, I encountered a problem.

Whilst following the tutorial, I got to this step: "For a Dapper User I am adding another class with the name MobileContext."

On line 3 of the code, it says:
 `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnector"].ToString());`

^ This is where I get my runtime/ compile error.

When I try to implement the same into my program, I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Project_v3.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here are my relevant files:

Server Explorer view: http://gyazo.com/288a07eb2ec5c2aa4ea25d1eb6eda187

Contents of FlightsTable: http://gyazo.com/9d1b014ecdba1e244c2f6957b6d9397c

Table Layout of FlightsTable: http://gyazo.com/b8a25fd48e725dc4690ed54bb3b0cca2

**FlightModel**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Project_v3.Models
{
    [Table("FlightsTable")]
    public class FlightModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int FlightID { set; get; }
        public string Departure { set; get; }
        public string Arrival { set; get; }
        public int NumberOfSeats { set; get; }
        public int NumberOfFlights { set; get; }
        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList FlightList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**FlightContext**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Dapper;
using System.Data;

namespace Project_v3.Models
{
    public class FlightContext
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnector"].ToString());
        public IEnumerable<FlightModel> GetFlightList()
        {
            string query = "SELECT [FlightID],[Departure]FROM [MyMainDBEntities2].[dbo].[FlightsList]";
            var result = con.Query<FlightModel>(query);
            return result;
        }  
    }
}
```

**MyTemplateController** (basically my HomeController):

```
FlightContext FCon = new FlightContext();
public ActionResult BookFlight()
{
    FlightModel FD = new FlightModel();

    FD.FlightList = new SelectList(FCon.GetFlightList(), "FlightID", "Departure");
    return View();
}
```

**EDIT** Web.config (as requested) however there are two:

Please See screenshot: http://gyazo.com/1bfb0886f82ac6dc2d1a739ddcb02999
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e7552b6ee5609205ac18

Would somebody be able to point out what I'm doing wrong/ where I've messed up? What have I missed that's causing this error to continue appearing?

**EDIT 3**: It works however I now get this error on this line of FlightContext: `var result = con.Query<FlightModel>(query)`;

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid object name 'MyMainDBEntities2.dbo.FlightsList'.
```

**EDIT 4**: 
`AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\[MyName]\Desktop\ASP.NET Project v3 - (Original - Edit Version)\Project v3\Project v3\App_Data\MyMainDB.mdf";Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework`

Comment: Can you post your configuration file (web.config)..?

Comment: where is your connection string. this statement `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnector"].ToString()` is not pointing to it. just check your config file for the same

Comment: I'm not sure you have to call `.ToString()` with `ConnectionStrings["name"]`

Comment: Table name is wrong in your query. Replace FlightsList with FlightsTable

Comment: @RahulNikate Yep thank you, I've noticed that. It's changed but still gives the same error. `An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid object name 'MyMainDBEntities2.dbo.FlightsTable'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the connection string in web.config named "MYConnector"

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnector"].ToString());
```

There is no connection string defined with name "MYConnector" in your web.config.
Create connection string in web.config like below

**web.config :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MYConnector" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=111.111.111.111;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;user id=UserName;password=Password;" />

</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Does it matter that I'm hosting the database on the Visual Studio 2013 solution file? Also; under which header do I place the `<add>` tag? Thanks!

Comment: @BorisSmith Right click on MyMainDBEntities2 database under data connections in server explorer and click Properties>Look for connection string. Take that connection string and add it to web.config

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have done so however I now get another error xD Please see edit 3. Thank you very much for the reply!

Comment: I have one more question. In MyMainDBEntities2 <- Located in the Server Explorer. When I right click and go to connection string, it says that my connection string contains the following: (see edit 4). Where would I place the additional code?

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config doesn't have the connection string named "MYConnector", try adding it into the web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="MYConnector" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="ConnectionStringHere" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Here's your reference to build a connection string:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

---

In that case, why not store the connectionstring as a string?

```
<configSections>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="MYConnector" value="ConnectionString"/>
   </appSettings>
</configSections>
```

In your code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MYConnector"].ToString());
```

Comment: Hi thank for the reply! Much appreciated. Is there a way to find the connection string? ie the `metadata=res://blabla`? Sorry, I am very new to this. Thanks!

Comment: It's wrong connection string. "<add name="conn" connectionString="ConnectionStringHere" />"

Comment: @BorisSmith Are you using entity framework?

Comment: @Mr.香港人 The tutorial I used said to use Dapper.

Comment: Depending on what kind of database you use, this site might help you to figure out the correct connection string: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: @BorisSmith Then I suggest to store the connectionstring as a string, and read the string directly, I'll update my answer

Comment: @BorisSmith I've updated, please try, see if it works

Comment: @Mr.香港人 That's fantastic, thanks! However, I have one more question. In `MyMainDBEntities2` <- Located in the Server Explorer. It says that my connection string contains the following: (see edit 4). Where would I place the additional code?

Comment: @BorisSmith Oh that's the connection string, put it in the "value", it should work